# Getting more than 700k followers ID from twitter using python

Tags: python, twitter

I was able to get the number of 75,000. After that, It keeps on pulling duplicate IDs. Here is my code. Can I get any suggestions so that I can correctly pull the large amount of follower Ids without duplicates?

```
import tweepy
import time

access_token = "..."
access_token_secret = "..."
consumer_key = "..."
consumer_secret = "..."

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


ids = []
while True:
    try:
        for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name = "...").pages():
            ids.extend(page)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        time.sleep(60*15)
        continue
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    break
```

Comment: i tried doing the same in on some twitter profiles with a couple of hundreds of followers and was not able to reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting duplicates, but you could put the values into a set rather than a list to remove them efficiently.

Just change `ids = []` to `ids = set()`

and `ids.extend(page)` to `ids.update(page)`